# 'fatal error: NSCoder not supported' when using UIViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, runtime-error, fatal-error

I am getting the following error when I try to run one of the View Controllers I hooked up to the default GameScene.swift file.

fatal error: NSCoder not supported:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("NSCoder not supported")
}
```

I am intending to use SpriteKit, so that's why I was prompted to use the required initializer, but I am not sure why this is causing a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not supposed to initialize using `required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` unless you've implemented it, (which is a [whole different topic](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/) that I won't digress to). Try another initializer, like `-initWithNibName:bundle:`.